# Convert NSArray value to int

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have problem with a `NSArray` object that a `json` service create it.
in my `NSArray` object there is just one object and it is a number.
when i debug code and watch `NSArray` Value with mouse over it show numbers in this format:`@""1""`.

when i want to convert it to int or `NSNumber` it return `0`. i checked it with a lot of approach.
and when I want to convert it to `NSString` and show `string` using `NSLog` or watch tool it will show it like "1".

these are some code of my efforts:

`data` is a `NSArray` Object:

```
NSString  *str = [data objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *number = [str integerValue];

int int1 =[[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"""" withString:@""] intValue];


number = [data objectAtIndex:0];
number = [[data objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
```

Comment: First convert it to correct format and use integerValue property to convert it to integer

Comment: Please print log of each of the value you got

Comment: Show Your array Values : **NSLog(@"%@", data)**

Comment: Please print the log each value you got and you try to gain

Comment: `NSInteger number = [str integerValue];` not `NSNumber *number`

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", data):   2013-12-16 11:31:09.847 Trial[3182:60b] (
    "\"1\""
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in your json, numbers are actually strings, try instead  with:

```
int int1 =[[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""] intValue];
```

Comment: yes webservice method return a string value. so it's work know probably. but in another case that i develop before i never seen this issue. thanks a lot